# How can I add text inside a switchery button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this plugin: http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/
Which allows me to add a switch button on my page.

I would like to add text inside the button itself, so that when the page loads, the button is set with "Employer" and if the user switches the button another text appears "Freelancer"

[image]

I know I need to grab the text and manipulate the field somehow using jQuery, but the problem is, I can't get the text to display within the button. It displays next to the button.

How can I do this?
Not the ability to change the text on button switch, I will get to that later as soon as I figure out to display the text inside the button itself.

This is my code so far, it's very simple and it works on document load, it changed the class from `hire` to `work` but nothing else happens at the moment because I am unable to print the text inside the switch button.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('span.user-role').text('Freelaner').removeClass('hire').addClass('work');
        });
    </script>
    <input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" checked />
    <span class="user-role text hire">Employer</span>
```

Comment: How did you increase width of switch element?

Comment: I didn't. The design I'm working with has it like this and I can't figure out how they did it, even though the author of the plugin said he has no plans to implement this feature: https://github.com/abpetkov/switchery/pull/37#issuecomment-52908628

Comment: Why you don't use any other plugin that has text?

Comment: I'm trying to stay consistent with the design, as this plugin is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use another plugin that has text by default but if you want to add text to button of this plugin, you need to have bit change on it.

Changes is:

1. Increase `width` of button and change first position of button
2. Add element of text to button
3. Add CSS of text to project
4. Add `onchange` event to show/hide text

```js
var elem = $(".js-switch")[0];
var init = new Switchery(elem);

$(".js-switch").siblings(".switchery").css("width", "100px")
  .prepend("<span>text</span>").find("small").css("left", "70px");

elem.onchange = function() {
    $(".switchery").find("span").toggle();
};
```

```css
.switchery > span {
    margin-left: 25px;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/dist/switchery.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/dist/switchery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" checked />
```

Comment: Now I get 2 switch buttons, one standard and one with the width your specified in your code. However, I only see `text` for a millisecond while the button switches and it disappears again. I think I'm gonna use another plugin which offers this feature because modifying this isn't gonna work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pseudo elements for that:

```
.switchery {
  width: 150px; // your width
}
.switchery:before {
  content: 'Work'; // your text
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.js-switch:checked + .switchery:before {
  color: #fff;
  left: 70px;
}
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/zBzxyB)